# Android:Program closes without error on devise

Tags: java, android

Sometime in random times(well thats how it seems)my game closes with out any error showing on devise(you know that annoying window that pops up)

In the eclipse i get this:

```
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101): Build fingerprint: 'google/passion/passion:2.3.5/Geno/102588:user/release-keys'
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101): pid: 2439, tid: 2448  >>> com.redsky.games.mygamename <<<
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000018
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  r0 00000000  r1 44d17934  r2 00000078  r3 00000000
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  r4 00000018  r5 44d17934  r6 00180198  r7 0017cd88
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  r8 44d17b6c  r9 44aece1c  10 44aece04  fp 00000de1
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  ip 01200000  sp 44d17918  lr 80c1e8e1  pc afd0cba8  cpsr 20000010
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d0  643a64696f72646e  d1  6472656767756265
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d8  43da800042200000  d9  4219999a00000000
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d10 000003204219999a  d11 00000027000001e0
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d12 000000003e99b009  d13 3e99b0093f800000
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d16 40b4ce0000000000  d17 7e37e43c8800759c
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d18 3fee915361e32d96  d19 3fa6eac9e1cd26a0
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d20 bc60000000000000  d21 3f6e77147ec6c8ff
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d22 3e21ec6244919fd4  d23 bda8fae9be8838d4
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d24 0000000000008a36  d25 0000000000000000
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d26 0000000000008a33  d27 0000000000000000
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d28 0000000000008a63  d29 0000000000000000
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  d30 0000000000000030  d31 0000000000000000
02-24 21:05:04.089: INFO/DEBUG(101):  scr 2000001b
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):          #00  pc 0000cba8  /system/lib/libc.so
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):          #01  pc 0001e8de  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):          #02  pc 0001ec74  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):          #03  pc 0001edae  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so (gliSetShaderProgram)
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):          #04  pc 00012f42  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so (validateShadowState)
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):          #05  pc 0000b218  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so (DrawTexture)
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): code around pc:
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): afd0cb88 e0240001 e2100003 1a000036 e591c000 
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): afd0cb98 e2522024 4a00001c f5d4f040 f5d1f040 
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): afd0cba8 e4940004 e5b1e004 e030000c 04940004 
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): afd0cbb8 05b1c004 0030000e 04940004 05b1e004 
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): afd0cbc8 0030000c 04940004 05b1c004 0030000e 
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): code around lr:
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): 80c1e8c0 0000023c 00000d98 0000012c ffffb6ed 
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): 80c1e8d0 ffffb700 ffffb713 229cb510 edcef7e9 
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): 80c1e8e0 bf00bd10 f5adb5f0 b0816d9e 91079006 
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): 80c1e8f0 28006800 80cef000 4a7cac0c f50d3c0c 
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): 80c1e900 2300619e 508b2601 6060469c 60a34637  
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101): stack:
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d178d8  0015a9b0  [heap]
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d178dc  afd4734c  
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d178e0  00004000  
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d178e4  00000000  
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d178e8  0000001b  
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d178ec  002b21a0  [heap]
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d178f0  44d17974  
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d178f4  44d17934  
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d178f8  00000000  
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d178fc  00000001  
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d17900  44d17954  
02-24 21:05:04.209: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d17904  80c1e6a1  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-24 21:05:04.219: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d17908  44d17934  
02-24 21:05:04.219: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d1790c  44d17974  
02-24 21:05:04.219: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d17910  df002777  
02-24 21:05:04.219: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d17914  e3a070ad  
02-24 21:05:04.219: INFO/DEBUG(101): #00 44d17918  00000004  
02-24 21:05:04.219: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d1791c  80c1e8e1  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-24 21:05:04.219: INFO/DEBUG(101): #01 44d17920  00000004  
02-24 21:05:04.219: INFO/DEBUG(101):     44d17924  80c1ec79  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
```

I guese this has something to do with memory and heap right ?

If yes what is the most possible senarios that cause this?

I dont give any of the code cause i dont know where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a native (non-Java) crash in your OpenGL ES driver. They occur mainly because that driver tends to be lamentably untested, but also because of applications doing silly things such as passing null byte[] pointers to an OpenGL ES API.

Comment: I did some small corrections on my code that deals with opengl and it fixed the problem(i dont know where exactly it was :) ). Thank you for your help